# Создание модального окна с подставлением контента в зависмости от того, через какой элемент было вызвано окно на php или js

Tags: javascript, php

Есть сайт, на нём у меня несколько одинаковых элементов, различающихся только контентом. Чтобы не писать лишний html я сделал структуру одного элемента, а все данные запихнул в массив php. При открытии сайта массив прогоняется через цикл и создаётся нужное кол-во элементов на странице с разными данными, но типовой структурой.

Код массива:

```
<?php

$software = [
    'Programm 1' => ['name' => 'Programm 1', 'downloads' => 77.2, 'image' => 'assets/img/programm.png'],
    'Programm 2' => ['name' => 'Programm 2', 'downloads' => 57.4, 'image' => 'assets/img/programm.png']

?>
```

Вывод в HTML:

```
<div class="uk-child-width-1-1 uk-grid-small uk-grid-divider" data-uk-grid="">
    <?php
        foreach($software as $soft){
    ?>
    <div>
        <div class="uk-flex-middle uk-grid-small" data-uk-grid="">
            <div class="uk-width-auto">
                <img class="programm-image" src="<?php echo $soft['image'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $soft['name'] ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-expand">
                <h5 class="uk-margin-remove"><?php echo $soft['name'] ?></h5>
                <p class="uk-text-xsmall uk-margin-remove"><?php echo $soft['downloads'] ?>K downloads</p>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-expand uk-text-right">
                <button class="uk-button uk-button-small uk-button-default">Download</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        };
    ?>
</div>
```

Как это на сайте выглядит:
[image: Вывод данных через массив php]

Мне нужно по кнопке download сделать popup, в который будут подставляться данные конкретно той программы, возле которой нажали эту кнопку, интересует именно, как по клику сделать вызов окна с нужными данными

Comment: А в чем проблема? Делайте попап. Вставляйте контент. На чем затык то?

Comment: Как раз в том, каким образом контент вставить